# Pointer being freed was not allocated with realloc and malloc in construct function

Tags: c++, pointers, free, realloc

I tried `dataPoolBuffer = realloc(dataPoolBuffer, sizeof(char)*(dataPoolSize));` already, but Xcode reports:assigning to 'char *' from imcompatible type 'void'.

I create a class:

```
class solutionBuffer{ 
private:


char * dataPoolBuffer;
char * consumerBuffer;
char * flagBuffer;
int dataPoolSize;
int consumerBufferSize;
mutex safe;

public:
solutionBuffer(){
    safe.lock();
    dataPoolSize = 0;
    consumerBufferSize = 0;
    
    dataPoolBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    consumerBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    flagBuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);
    
}
int add(char* data, int length)
{
   
    dataPoolSize += length;
    
    realloc(dataPoolBuffer, sizeof(char)*(dataPoolSize));
    
    realloc(flagBuffer, sizeof(char)*(dataPoolSize));
    
    memcpy(dataPoolBuffer + dataPoolSize - length, data, sizeof(char)*(length));
    
    return 0;
}

~solutionBuffer(){
    printf("%d",strlen(dataPoolBuffer));
    free(dataPoolBuffer);
    free(consumerBuffer);
    free(flagBuffer);
    safe.unlock();
}

};
```

Every time when we call `.add` function, it will `realloc` memory for the variable. However, when I do that in `main()`:

```
char data[] = "0123456789";
char data2[] = "01234567890123456789";
solutionBuffer buffer;
buffer.add(data, 10);
buffer.add(data2, 20);
```

The xoce shows:pointer being freed was not allocated in `~solutionBuffer()` when it was trying to free `dataPoolBuffer` .
Why it does like that? How to fix that ?

Comment: There's so many things that are wrong here, I don't even know where to start: `malloc` with a size of 0; using `malloc` and `free` in C++ code; needless dynamic allocation in the first place. The list just goes on, and on, and on...

Comment: Even I revise malloc it with size of 1, it still shows the error msg. C++ is compatible with C style. Why cannot use that in C++

Comment: I understand the reason for using `realloc`. But I want to know what possible reason you think there is for latching a mutex (incorrectly) in a class' constructor, where said-same modifies only instance-member variables. Are you expecting multiple threads to be constructing the same object simultaneously? Or that you ignore said-mutex in a method I would expect it to be latched (but not how you're doing it) such as your `add` method. If it isn't needed to repro your findings, get rid of it in your post.

Comment: And regarding your actual problem, what do you think the *result* of `realloc` is *for* ? I think you should review what it returns, and why ignoring it is a *bad* idea. Read how [**`realloc`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc) works, because you're using it *wrong*.

Comment: Just because it's possible to invoke malloc/realloc/free from C++ doesn't mean that it's a good idea to do so.

Comment: @beasone I highly suggest you learn proper C++ programming before you jump to multithreaded program.

Comment: I want to make a class, the function inside the class is thread safe, so I use mutex to lock it. Each time when someone call .add to add more data into the dataPoolBuffer, it will realloc more memory to contain the new data.

Comment: @beasone Why not simply use `std::vector<char>` instead of `char *`, and `vector::resize()` instead of those `realloc` calls?

Comment: @WhozCraig  Are you expecting multiple threads to be constructing the same object simultaneously?  Yes.  Or I shoud say, I need to make sure all these functions are thread safe.

Comment: @beasone a mutex on a constructor as you have it isn't the way to do that. You're not updating some external data; it's all member stuff. And seriously, how do you expect two threads to be *constructing* the **same** object *simultaneously* ? "Thread-safe" doesn't mean hang mutexes on stuff and latch them, particularly how you're doing it, as you needlessly latch a mutex, and its never unlatched again.

Comment: @beasone -- Start [with this](http://ideone.com/sJJTh7).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie .. and then throw out `dataPoolSize`, since the vector already has a member that reports it =P

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, that can be gotten rid of.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik malloc(0) is OK

Comment: @beasone [Updated example](http://ideone.com/0ZJXnv).  See how much simpler and saner that looks, compared to your code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your code. Actually I need three functions inside this class, I didn't post all of them. the add function will never block the process or thread, another function will be blocked if the dataPoolBuffer is empty and it will be released when dataPoolBuffer is filled with new data.

Comment: @bassone - As I stated, start with that example.  As for checking for an empty buffer -- `if ( dataPoolBuffer.empty()) { }` -- can anything be more simpler than that?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I can do that.  How to make each function thread safe?

Comment: That's a majorly destructive edit of your post after the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc),

```
realloc(dataPoolBuffer, sizeof(char)*(dataPoolSize));
```

reallocates `dataPoolBuffer`, but doesn't change where `dataPoolBuffer` points. So odds are pretty good that `dataPoolBuffer` is now pointing to invalid memory.

```
dataPoolBuffer = (char*)realloc(dataPoolBuffer, sizeof(char)*(dataPoolSize));
```

will do you what you want, but rethink how you are doing this. You're setting yourself up for a lot of pain. [Your class violates The Rule of Three, for one thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) will handle all of container resizing and memory management for you with no muss and no fuss.

Comment: I tried "ataPoolBuffer = realloc(dataPoolBuffer, sizeof(char)*(dataPoolSize));" already, but Xcode reports:assigning to 'char *' from imcompatible type 'void'.

Comment: @beasone Good point. I fell back on C where this gag is legal. Needs an extra cast. Fixing.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `realloc()`, you need to assign the result back to the pointer variable. `realloc()` often needs to move the memory to a new location, and it returns that location. Your code leaves the variable pointing to the old location, and you get undefined behavior when you try to use it after that.

So it should be:

```
dataPoolBuffer = (char*)realloc(dataPoolBuffer, sizeof(char)*(dataPoolSize));

flagBuffer = (char*)realloc(flagBuffer, sizeof(char)*(dataPoolSize));
```

Comment: I tried "ataPoolBuffer = realloc(dataPoolBuffer, sizeof(char)*(dataPoolSize));" already, but Xcode reports:assigning to 'char *' from imcompatible type 'void'.

Comment: Forgot that C++ requires you to use an explicit cast there.